# Entity Framework database-first and automatically setting concurrency token for all tables

Tags: entity-framework

I am using the entity framework (EF 4.5 using the POCO template that uses the DbContext) and I have a very large model.

Every table in the model has an integer column (named RowVersion). I want to set this column as the concurrency column automatically.

I do not want to manually do this for every table in the EDMX file. And going forward for maintenance I do not want to have to remember to do this.

I was hoping there was something I could add to the context to do this automatically for all tables for me.

I seen this piece of code on another post

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<myEntity>().Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
}
```

But this appears to only be for code-first, as the event never gets fired for my model.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: ModelBuilder is indeed for codefirst, db/model first uses the design space, however im not too sure where this particular option might be found

Comment: So there would be no way to automatically change the model? Rather than do it manually in the design view?